# Entity framework resiliency and retry logic

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-functions

I get a lot of errors when adding data to my Azure SQL server like this:

> An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient
>   failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using

I can see on following link you can implement an azure strategy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-resiliency/retry-logic

In the article it is illustrated that you can use a standard Azure strategy:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
    }
}
```

However it isent described how you apply it to your DbContext. Anyone tried this and can share som experience? It is not the core version, and it is implemented in a function. Out of 9000 call around 1000 fails so it a lot of errors.

Comment: What is the sku/plan of your azure sql database ?

Comment: Right now it is Standard S0: 10 DTUs but I can change it to higher if it improves stability in any way.

Comment: Is it because I exeed the DTU?

Comment: I think your right. Inner exception is "The request limit for the database is 60 and has been reached". Kind of strange as my function is as a maximum running 10 concurrent instances.

Comment: I think with free tiers you're really limited. Try to update to 50 DTU then it should od the trick for dev/test workload

Comment: I tried S3 still get throttled. The request limit for the database is 200 and has been reached. All calls are enclosed in using statements wonder how the requests are calculated. I most do some analysis here or move to a cosmos db. Thanks for your input very helpful!

Comment: How many request are you doing ? Maybe you should keep the sql connection open

Comment: Its multiple azure app functions running concurrently. Each function is actually not doing that many, but some calls inserts a lot in one time. Dont know if that can be optimized.    using (var db = new DB(_dbConnStr))
            {
                db.DeleteSiteUsers(site.SPOSiteId);

                db.SiteUsers.AddRange(owners);
                db.SaveChanges();

                db.SiteUsers.AddRange(members);
                db.SaveChanges();
            } each of the AddRange inserts around 1000 small enitites.

Comment: Check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `DbConfigurationType` attribute on the context class, specifying that it is to use your `MyConfiguration` class:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyConfiguration))]
public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
{
    ...
}
```